# Measuring the overlap between two probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, distance, distance-functions

I have many probability distributions, I need to compute **the amount of overlap between two probability distributions**. I don't know the type of distribution since it really depends on the data itself.

[image]

My question is what appropriate approach that should I use for this case?

Comment: You may also want to look into Kullback-Leibler distance.

Comment: It is rare for such a computation to be statistically meaningful, suggesting you might mean "overlap" in some general sense that differs from that of the duplicate.  If so, please explain your purpose.

Comment: @stans The Kullback-Leibler divergence (not distance) is overrated. Better options are Jensen-Shannon Distance or Jeffrey's divergence

Comment: @whuber what's the basis to make the claim that such computation is rarely statistically meaningful? Such a computation can have intuitive and pragmatic meaning. Not every analysis requires statistical purity to gain some practical understanding.

Comment: @Mari153 What would this "overlap" be and what would it mean, then?  The question doesn't indicate.  One is led to suspect that there's a different underlying problem and that supplying *any* proposed overlap calculation could be useless, misleading, or wrong.

Comment: @whuber, as one example, such an overlap would provide a measure of the commonality/similarity between two or more distributions.  That has a natural intuitive understanding and - dear I say - a more practical meaning than, say, a theoretical p-value (or effect size) that drives much of statistical reasoning. Critically, such a measure would neither be useless, misleading nor wrong. It would simply be different to what is more commonly accepted by statistical conventions and hegemony,

Comment: @Mari The relevance or applicability of that measure to statistical questions is doubtful.  Indeed, because many distributions don't even have densities, that alone shows that this measure cannot be generally useful.

Comment: @whuber. Yes i well aware that that some (mostly highly theoretical) distributions don't have densities. However for those that do - like in this question - then such a measure can provide practical meaning and insight. Thanks for the exchange in ideas.

Comment: @Mari I am left wondering what specific practical meaning or insight it is you might be referring to.  Examples of meaningful and practical applications of the overlap areas of density functions are scarce.  BTW, distributions like Bernoulli, Binomial, and Poisson are far from "highly theoretical" -- yet they do not have PDFs.

Comment: @whuber. To answer the implied question in your first sentence.  Irrigation uniformity comparing different sprinklers or different pressures/flow rates of the same sprinkler.  Assessing the overlap is quite useful really. Love stats that are practical.

Comment: @Mari153 I would love to see a clear example of that, because the potential application of overlap of probability density functions to sprinklers is just as obscure as the possible insight that sprinkler systems might offer for probability calculations.